# Generate unique json object name gson in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

How would I be able to generate a new object based on the object names below. What I am trying to do here is that when there is no Object1, gson will generate Object1 with the values below and when there is Object1, gson will generate Object2 and so on.

```
{
    "Object1": {
        "Name": "Object1",
        "Color": "Orange",
        "Food": "Pizza"
    },
    "Object2": {
        "Name": "Object2",
        "Color": "Blue",
        "Food": "Pineapple"
    }
}
```

Comment: add some related code

Comment: @Basi Thanks for helping me out but I can't add related code since I really don't know how to do this. I tried using POJO but I don't think it will work. I am trying to make an app that when the user adds a device there will be a new object and its preferences will be generated and displayed on the home screen inside a recycler view. I want it to be like the smart home devices wherein you can add a device and control it in home screen

Comment: What do you mean by `Object1` and `Object2`? Are they supposed to be 2 different classes or 2 instances of the same class? Also, are you always expecting to receive `Object1` and `Object2` in your JSON or could they change dynamically?

Comment: @Zoe Thanks for telling me that. I will not repeat me again. I really thought I could use it since I use android studio to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating an unique property in your class object means you could dynamically have a class lets say Example.

```
FoodData {
 var object1 : Food?
 var object2 : Food?
 // And so on...
}
```

For me this seems like a structural problem. Your response should be **specific** to the data structure you have and need. A more acceptable approach would be:

```
[
     {
        "Name": "Object1",
        "Color": "Orange",
        "Food": "Pizza",
        "someAttr" : "Object1"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Object2",
        "Color": "Blue",
        "Food": "Pineapple",
        "someAttr" : "Object2"
    }
]
```

And then it would make more sense to have a list of food like :

```
FoodData {
 var listFood: List<Food>?

}
```